# How to send email from Excel Script Lab?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, outlook-restapi, scriptlab

I am trying to send email from Excel script lab.

Based on my researching, it seems I need to use `graph api`.

Is there any library support in Excel Script lab?

I could not use [msgraph-sdk-javascript](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues?page=2&q=without+require) since we could not use `import` or `require` in `Excel Script Lab`

Answer (score 0):

See [Send mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more information. But you are not limited to MS Graph. You can use any APIs or services for sending emails from your JavaScript code. But please remember that ScriptLab just interprets your code, so it can't install any package.